# Java SE, DAO, MySql, Swing

Tags: mysql, swing, java-ee, dao

Всем привет. Делаю дэскттопное приложение на виндоус 10 на старой библиотеке SWING. Все работает, нормально. Но просто решил спросить, нормально ли это.У меня есть несколько таблиц в MySQL, в одном из JFrame у меня появляются две таблицы на скролах, я ,к примеру ,выбираю из одной таблицы что то , и у меня считывает id этой таблицы и выводит все в JTextArea вот таким вот способом.

Отрывок из DAO:

```
private PreparedStatement psSelect = null;

private void selectVitPS(String sql) {
    if (psSelect != null) {
        try {
            psSelect = db.getCn().prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String select(int id) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String s = null;
    List<Vitamins> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        selectVitPS("SELECT * FROM vitamins WHERE id_vitamin =" + id);
        rs = psSelect.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vitamins v = new Vitamins();
            v.setVitamin(rs.getString("vitamin"));
            list.add(v);
        }
        s = list.toString();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (psSelect != null) {
            try {
                psSelect.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return s;

}
```

Отрывок из фрейма : 
происходит по нажатию на кнопку :

```
  private JTextArea area;

  public void action(){

  update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(table1.getSelectedRow() != -1){
                DaoVitamins dv = new DaoVitamins();
                area.setText(dv.select(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(table1.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0)))));
                }
            if(table2.getSelectedRow() != -1){
                         DaoDiscriptions dd = new DaoDiscriptions();
                area.setText(dv.select(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(table2getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0)))));

            }
```

все выводит что мне надо, но нормально ли так делать ? 
нужен совет. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAO оставил без изменений, изменил метод  update.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){} в фрейме, а именно изменил

```
    if(table1.getSelectedRow() != -1){
    DaoVitamins dv = new DaoVitamins();
    area.setText(dv.select(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(table1.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0)))));
    }
    if(table2.getSelectedRow() != -1){
             DaoDiscriptions dd = new DaoDiscriptions();
    area.setText(dv.select(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(table2getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0)))));

}
```

на

```
    if (table1.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
        DaoVitamins dv = new DaoVitamins();
        area.append(
                dv.select(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(table1.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0)))));
        area.append("\n");
        updateTable();
    }
    if (table2.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
        DaoDiscriptions dd = new DaoDiscriptions();
        area.append(
                dd.select(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(table2.getValueAt(table2.getSelectedRow(), 0)))));
        area.append("\n");
        updateTable();
    }
}
```

метод updateTable() прпосто обновляет содержимое таблицы.